# how to make war file of Angular 5 Application to deploy on web logic server?

Tags: java, angular, eclipse, angular5, war

**Hi, I have developed an Angular 5 application. we have a requirement to deploy that angular application on Oracle web logic server. Any Ideas on how to accomplish the task?
Thanks in Advance for your response.**

Comment: what about your backend is it spring-boot??

Comment: yes, it is! front end is angular

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-deployment have a look at it

Comment: @Vikas i went through this link , but it is not helping my issue. thankyou.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: assets folder files are not accessible to App.after build the angular, when I deploy the app on Tomcat, all asset file paths are not found!